# Intermarriage among Middle eastern Jews right before 1948

Tags: history, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, statistics, intermarriage

I was wondering does anyone know where I can find out the Intermarriage rate among Middle eastern Jews right before 1948 particularly amongst the Iraqis and the Syrians?

Answer (score 1):

Syrian Jews have been under "the takkanah", forbidding them to marry converts, since the early part of the 20th century. Though the takkanah was promulgated by the rabbis of the American Syrian community, it seems to be applicable to Syrian communities elsewhere in North and South America as well. (I don't know about Israel.)

They boast an intermarriage rate of only 3%.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syrian_Jews#Attitudes_to_conversion)

Comment: The rate of 3% is current, the question is in regard to the 1940s

Comment: I believe the takana was for the halabim